# Installing protobuf for python using pip, virtualenv and cpp_representation

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to install protobuf and I'm stuck with an error when executing my app:

```
import Request_pb2
  File "blablabla/Request_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "blablabla/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 50, in <module>
from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: blablabla/.virtualenvs/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so: undefined symbol:
 _ZTIN6google8protobuf10TextFormat17FieldValuePrinterE
```

I installed the c++ version 2.6.1 of protocol buffers. And writting protoc --version I get:

```
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

Then, I installed protobuf for python, using pip and virtualenv (virtualenvwrapper). I write

```
env CPATH=$PROTOBUF_HOME:$PROTOBUF_HOME/src LIBRARY_PATH=$PROTOBUF_HOME/.libs 
pip install protobuf 
--install-option="--cpp_implementation"
```

As I read here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/144

In my .bashrc file (and accessible from command line):

```
export PROTOBUF_HOME=~/projects/protobuf-2.6.1

#Python Protobuf configuration.
export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp
export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION=2
```

I re-compiled .proto file just in case, because I had the 2.6.0 version previously.

What is It happening?
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
ldd _message.so
```

Returns:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3e1f8000)
libprotobuf.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8 (0x00007f12b8a43000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f12b873f000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f12b8528000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f12b8163000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f12b7f45000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f12b7d2b000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f12b7a25000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f12b8f81000)
```

Taking a look:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8
```

Returns:

```
dic  9 10:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8 -> libprotobuf.so.8.0.0
```

Taking a look:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8.0.0
```

Returns:

```
feb 13  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8.0.0
```

Comment: The missing symbol is a typeinfo object, which I think is only included if you compile with RTTI enabled. Is it possible that libprotobuf.so was compiled with `-fno-rtti`? If so, recompile it without that flag, or compile the Python module *with* the flag. Otherwise, the problem is probably a version mismatch somewhere, but it's hard to say from here.